# Proof matrices and their eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, algebraic-graph-theory, graph-laplacian

Let $C=A-B$ where $A=\begin{bmatrix}I &0\\ 0&0\end{bmatrix}$ and $B$ is a Laplacian matrix of a connected graph, so sum for rows is null and it doesn't have any zero row(or column).  Eigenvalues of B are in [0,1) . $A$, $B$ and $C$ have the same dimension.

I think it's can be proved that $\lambda_i(C)\neq1$.

Comment: So, $B$ is a matrix whose only eigenvalues are $-1$ and $0$, and whose row-sums are all zero.  Is that right?

Comment: Is there any reason you have for thinking that this would be the case, anyway?

Answer (score 2):

**Counterexample:**
$$
A = 
\pmatrix{
1&0&0\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&0
},\;
B= \pmatrix{
0&0&0\\
0&-1/2&1/2\\
0&1/2&-1/2
}
$$
As for your newest question, note that Laplacian matrices are always [positive semidefinite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix#Properties) (i.e. have only non-negative eigenvalues).  Since the sum of two positive semidefinite matrices is itself positive semidefinite, $C$ will be positive semidefinite and thus cannot have $-1$ as an eigenvalue.

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: Is there any reason you believe this should be the case?  It may help if you provide some context for the problem.

Comment: Laplacian matrix doesn't have any null row

Comment: And presumably the diagonals are also non-zero

Comment: Yes the diagonals are nonzero

Comment: Do you have a Laplacian matrix with $-1$ as an eigenvalue?  According to wikipedia, this should be impossible.

Comment: strictly greater than -1 sorry

Comment: But why would your matrix have any negative eigenvalues?

Comment: Because it is B=-L where L  is the laplacian

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you are wrong. My counterexample:
$$B=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
 0 & -1 & 1 & 0\\
0&0&-1&1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}
\\A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: I edited my question